# How to write this sql,left join,sum query in Laravel? How to use sum with left join in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sum, structure

I want to write this query in laravel,

My table structures are

There is a user id
$user_id = Auth::id();

****CARTS->
ID|USER_ID|FOOD_ID|QUANTITY|STATUS****

**FOOD->
ID|NAME|PRICE**

```
SELECT sum(food.price*carts.quantity) as total 
from carts  
left join food on carts.food_id=food.id 
where user_id=$user_id and status='0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try this way:

```
$res = DB::table('carts')
         ->select(DB::Raw('SUM(food.price*carts.quantity) AS total'))
         ->leftJoin('food', 'carts.food_id', 'foods.id')
         ->where('carts.user_id', $user_id)
         ->where('carts.status', 0)
         ->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Query Builder:

```php
$amount = \DB::table('carts')
        ->where('carts.user_id', $user)
        ->where('carts.status', '!=', 0)
        ->leftJoin('foods', 'carts.food_id', 'foods.id')
        ->sum(\DB::raw('carts.quantity * foods.price'));
```